# What to do when Apple IIc displays 'check disk drive' alert

Tags: repair, apple-iic

I have an Apple IIc ROM version 3, with original program discs. A few years ago I dusted it off for fun. I found online a suggested way to network it with a PC. What I remember from a few years ago was that I used a serial to USB cord to connect the iic to a pc. I recall running a program (proDOS I think, or ADT) from the PC, to integrate the iic as a dumb terminal, for example to display the pc cpu usage as I recall.

The disc drive with floppies worked prior this. But after running the (?) proDOS transfer, it did not, and I regretted the attempt.

I still get 'check disk drive' repetively, despite trialling multiple floppys which otherwise appear in good condition. The computer makes the typical start up noises but they cease quite quickly.

I ran the inbuilt self test in which case the screen briefly flashes the patterned screen then goes blank.

I would very much appreciate a suggested next step.

Comment: What did you actually do to “network it with a PC”?

Comment: Mind to add what you're actually doing? What disk is loaded? Have you tried different disks? Or without?

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that you broke it by doing something (which we do not have the details of).  Can you simply undo what you did?

Comment: Going from memory the //c has a lot of ports on the back for an external drive, serial, printer, video, mouse, etc.  If you were 'hooking' one of these up to your PC and connected a power rail somewhere you shouldn't, you could easily fry something.  It would be helpful to know more about what you were doing when 'networking with a PC'.  What port?  What pins?  etc.

Comment: One other thought to throw out, this error could be as simple as a dirty r/w head on the floppy drive.  Usually cleaning the r/w head with some 99% isopropyl alcohol will clear up the issue.  Assuming that is all it is...

Comment: Thank you, I have added deatil to my question, and I will clean the drive head.